# ListView with GridView, disable focusable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, gridview

I'm working on a WPF application bound to Entity Framework following MVVM pattern.
I have a ListView which contains a GridView.

```
<ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding DocumentTypeCount.DocumentTypeCountList}" Width="Auto" Margin="5, 0,0,5" Focusable="False">
    <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                        <Style>
                            <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </Style>
                </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Document Type" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DocumentTypeName}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Count" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Count}"/>
            </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

This is rendering like this:

[image: ListView rendering]

My questions are:
1- How can I disable the focus on the rows? I have tried with the property Focusable on ListViewItem but it didn't work.
2- How can I apply a different font style (Bold) to the last item?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you want to get rid of selection and if that's the case you should use [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) control instead of `ListView` and to make it look like `ListView` columns you can use shared size scope `Grid` as your `ItemTemplate`

```
<ItemsControl 
    ItemsSource="{Binding DocumentTypeCount.DocumentTypeCountList}"
    Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>            
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsTotals}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Grid.Resources>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="column1"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="column2"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DocumentTypeName}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Count}" Grid.Column="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

as for making last element display bold it would be much easier if you would add another bool column, apart from `DocumentTypeName` and `Count`, to your model behind each item, lets say `IsTotals`, which, when true, would make text bold via `DataTrigger`, as in the example above. If you cannot add another column but *Total* is a unique name you can trigger on that

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DocumentTypeName}" Value="Total">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
<ListBox
   Width="Auto"
   Grid.Column="0"
   Grid.Row="1"
   Margin="5, 0,0,5"
   Focusable="False"
   Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DocumentTypeCount.DocumentTypeCountList}">
   <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
         <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                  <ContentPresenter/>
               </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </Style>
   </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   <ListBox.Resources>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DocumentTypes:DocumentType}">
         <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="CountColumn"/>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DocumentTypeName}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Count}"/>
         </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DocumentTypes:TotalsDocumentType}">
         <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="CountColumn"/>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding DocumentTypeName}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Count}"/>
         </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

Key things to note are the ItemContainerStyle. This will remove the highlighting behaviour that you are not wanting.

Second, I decided to use a listbox with a SharedSizeScope. The Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" property on the listbox, coupled with the SharedSizeGroup="CountColumn", enable the count to appear as they are in one column.

Additionally, to show only the last row in bold, I would recommend doing this with different types of ViewModels. Here you can see for the generic row I have defined a "DocumentType" ViewModel. For the totals, a "TotalsDocumentType" view model. This has allowed me to give a different data template for the last item (this could also be done by a StyleSelector). DocumentType and TotalsDocumentType share a common base class, and therefore can be contained within the same ObservableCollection. These differing types of view models will also allow you to treat the rows in different ways for specific business logic which I presume you need.

Comment: Thank you. I fund the marked answer more simply. I didn't try your solution but I think it will work as well.